# Anexar arquivo TXT usando Javamail

Tags: java, android, javamail

Estou usando o Javamail para envio de email, com anexo, no Android.

Ao anexar um arquivo com extensão ".txt" ele está atribuindo o conteúdo ao corpo do email, e não como arquivo anexado.

Meu código para anexo de arquivos:

```java
public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {

    DataSource file = new FileDataSource(filename);

    BodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(file)); 
    attachment.setFileName(filename);

    multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
}
```

Fiz um teste, alterando a extensão do arquivo para ".tx" e o mesmo veio anexado como arquivo. Como faço para anexar o ".txt" como arquivo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que você tenha que dizer explicitamente que esse "BodyPart" é um anexo, adicione essa linha:

```java
attachment.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
```

Ou ainda tente fazer dessa maneira (**Exemplo completo**):

```java
public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    DataSource file = new FileDataSource(filename){  

        public String getContentType() {  
            return "application/octet-stream";  
        }  
    };
    MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(file));
    attachmentPart.setFileName(filename);

    // Acredito que só essa linha já resolveria seu problema
    attachmentPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);

    multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
}
```

O que eu utilizo não é com File e sim com byte[], é assim:

```java
DataHandler handlerAttach = new DataHandler(
new ByteArrayDataSource(binary, "application/octet-stream"));
```

Pensando assim tente a opção da resposta do **[Dante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26335/2998)**:

```java
DataSource file = new FileDataSource(filename){
   public String getContentType() {  
       return "application/octet-stream";  
   }  
};
```

Comment: não funcionou. Continua vindo no corpo do email. Alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: @felipearon, tente adicionar o mimeType 'application/octet-stream'. Verifique resposta atualizada.

Comment: deu **erro**: IOException while sending message;
javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type application/octet-stream

Comment: @felipearon, veja edição na resposta.

Comment: dessa forma funcionou, assim como mencionei na resposta do Dante. Único detalhe é que visualizando pelo Thunderbird ele mostra no corpo e não como anexo.

Comment: @felipearon, dai já acredito que seja particularidades de cada gerenciador de email, em tratamento dos anexos.

Answer (score 3):

Cara, o que eu utilizo está assim:

```
public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String message, String attach)     {  

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();  
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject, CHARSET);  

        Address addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);  
        mimeMessage.setFrom(addressFrom);  
        mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  

        // Texto  
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/plain");  
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

        //Anexo  
        File file = new File(attach);  
        DataSource ds = new FileDataSource(file) {  

            public String getContentType() {  
                return "application/octet-stream";  
            }  
        };  

        BodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();  
        mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));  
        mbp.setFileName(file.getName());  
        mbp.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);  
        multipart.addBodyPart(mbp);  

        mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);  
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);  
}
```

Percebi que no seu código não tem a linha:

```
mbp.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
```

Tenta adicionar dessa forma no seu código e testa:

```
attachmentPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
```

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou corretamente. Só um **detalhe**: Abrindo o email pelo Thunderbird o conteúdo do arquivo consta no corpo do email. Pelo Browser (gmail) ele mostra como anexo.

Comment: @felipearon Pode ser algum problema específico do Thunderbird...eu abro aqui com o Outlook e o e-mail vem como arquivo anexado, é estranho. Você tem necessidade de abrir pelo Thunderbird?

Comment: Não tenho necessidade não. Já fiz um teste com o cliente, e ele também recebeu em anexo. Então fechou!

Comment: Sucesso então! Se ele tiver alguma necessidade de baixar assim algum dia, indica o Outlook para ele que funciona do mesmo jeito! Não sei se podem ter mais de uma resposta marcada como correta, mas se tiver, marca a minha também! Abraços!

Comment: Então Dante, infelizmente não tem como dar 2 respostas corretas. Como o @fernando respondeu o mesmo que você, e foi o primeiro a responder, marquei o dele como certo. Mas de qualquer forma, valeu também, ajudou muito. :)

Comment: Ta tudo tranquilo! Sucesso pra ti!

Comment: Boa a sacada de sobrescrever o método `getContentType` do `FileDataSource`. +1.